# Git Or GitPython Check Is File Deleted

Tags: git, gitpython

I am new at using git and also gitPython. I have a project. A part of my project I should check if any file is deleted with its created commit(first commit) sha key?

for example;

```
git log -1 -- file2.txt  #not file, desired first sha key
```

result;

```
commit f9e12411bc0eb2131f417fa0ffa4e31adab987ac (HEAD -> master)
Author: yilmazedis <ylmazedis@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 18 12:16:15 2018 +0300

    deleted repo
```

In the above commit sha is last operation commit. I want to check with its first commit. Sorry this question may be trivial. Please help me for this approach.

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this?

Comment: This was a school internship project. I made it through a long way. This project ended up for me instant. My teachers may be able to involve me in the future. But I still wonder the answer to this question. Thank you for your interest.